# flag not updating through the multiprocessor in same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Used three multiprocessor. The `self.state` flag is not updating when the `current_time == self.scheduled_time`

`print("Time reached", self.state)`  is working when the `current_time == self.scheduled_time` . But the `print(f"{self.state}")` under `printer_part()`  multiprocessing is not working, its always printing the `False`

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
from datetime import datetime


class test:
    def __init__(self,scheduled_time):
        self.scheduled_time = scheduled_time
        self.state = False
        
    def time_checker(self):
        while True:
            current_time = (datetime.now()).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            if current_time == self.scheduled_time:
                self.state = True
                print("Time reached", self.state)

    def printer_part(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            print(f"{self.state}")

    def start_rec(self):
        print("Phase 1")

    def main_pro(self):
        print_proc = mp.Process(target=self.printer_part, args=())
        checker_proc = mp.Process(target=self.time_checker, args=())
        print_proc.start()
        checker_proc.start()
        while True:
            start_proc = mp.Process(target=self.start_rec, args=())
            start_proc.start()
            time.sleep(1)

        start_proc.terminate()
        print_proc.terminate()
        checker_proc.terminate()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheduled_time = "02:17:00"

    test_obj= test(scheduled_time)
    test_obj.main_pro()
```

Comment: This is not how multiprocessing works: By starting a process you create a clone of `test_obj` in an extra memory space. There is no sharing of the `state` property between those clones.

Comment: But i need the test_obj , becuause there are lots of ther variables under __init__()  (i didn't mentioned here, here just a sample portion of it)  which i should used with other functions in the class .How can i share the state property then  ?

Comment: [Read here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) (don't get confused by the use of the word "state" - it's just coincidental that your variable is named "state" too).

Comment: I have edited the code now. Please check it. I hope the test_obj won't take extra memory space now.

Comment: I don't see how this resolves the basic problem. IMHO this won't work. Have you checked if it does?

Comment: I also think `main_pro` will never reach the termination part at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit that I don't quite see why you need multiprocessing for a task like the one in your example code. But that might be due to me not knowing enough about the context and/or the simplification you have done to make the problem presentable.

There are ways in which processes can communicate with each other: pipes, queues and shared memory objects. In the following attempt to achieve something like in your example code I have used a pipe, because this is an easy way:

```
import multiprocessing as mp, time
from datetime import datetime

class Test:

    def __init__(self, scheduled_time):
        self.scheduled_time = scheduled_time

    def time_checker(self, conn):
        while True:
            if datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S") == self.scheduled_time:
                conn.send(True)
                print("time_checker: Time reached!")
                break
            print("time_checker: Still waiting...")
            time.sleep(1)

    def printer_part(self, conn):
        while True:
            if conn.poll():
                state = conn.recv()
                if state is True:
                    print("printer_part:", True)
                    break
            print("printer_part:", False)
            time.sleep(1)

    def main_pro(self):
        p_conn, c_conn = mp.Pipe(duplex=False)
        print_proc = mp.Process(target=self.printer_part, args=(p_conn,))
        checker_proc = mp.Process(target=self.time_checker, args=(c_conn,))
        print_proc.start()
        checker_proc.start()
        print_proc.join()
        checker_proc.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheduled_time = "23:22:00"
    test_obj = Test(scheduled_time)
    test_obj.main_pro()
```

Be aware that the code isn't very elegant and efficient. That's because my focus was mostly on showing what is possible.

Maybe it helps...